# Issue with retrieving data in php from retrofit @Body form

Tags: android, retrofit

I wrote some code for posting data with @Body annotation in android studio and retrofit but I can't retrieve that is php. It just send me a blank variable

this is my android code

```
@POST("process_post.php")
Call<Response> sendPost(@Body ExamplePost post);
```

This is ExamplePost variables

```
@SerializedName("name")
private String guitaristName ;
@SerializedName("guitar")
private String guitaristGuitar;
@SerializedName("age")
private int guitaristAge ;
```

And finally this is my php code

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    $json = file_get_contents('php//input');
    $data = json_decode($json,true);
    $name = $data['name'];
    $guitar = $data['guitar'];
    $age = $data ['age'];

    $response = array();
    $response["code"] = 1;
    $response["server"] = $name . " : " . $guitar . " : " . $age;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: if you are using `@Body` you are sending the data by json, you should use php://input to get the json then decode it.

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA I change it like the above code (I edit my topics php code ) but still I can't retrieve anything

Comment: you missing `:` in `php://input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. Try this.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: i am using the same line, but in loss